# Store JSON directly in bash script with variables?

Tags: json, bash

I'm going to preface by saying that "no, find a different way to do it" is an acceptable answer here.

Is there a reliable way to store a short bit of JSON in a bash variable for use in a AWS CLI command running from the same script?

I'll be running a job from Jenkins that's updating an AWS Route53 record, which requires UPSERTing a JSON file with the change in records. Because it's running from Jenkins, there's no local storage where I can keep this file, and I'd really like to avoid needing to do a git checkout every time this project will run (which will be once an hour).

Ideally, storing the data in a variable (`$foo`) and calling it as part of the `change-resource-record-sets` command would be most convenient given the Jenkins setup, but I'm unfamiliar with exactly how to quote/store JSON inside bash - can it be done safely?

The specific JSON in this case is the following;

```
{"Comment":"Update DNSName.","Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"alex.","Type":"A","AliasTarget":{"HostedZoneId":"######","DNSName":"$bar","EvaluateTargetHealth":false}}}]}
```

As an added complication the DNSName value - `$bar` - needs to be expanded.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You could use a here-doc:

```
foo=$(cat <<EOF
{"Comment":"Update DNSName.","Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"alex.","Type":"A","AliasTarget":{"HostedZoneId":"######","DNSName":"$bar","EvaluateTargetHealth":false}}}]}
EOF
)
```

By leaving `EOF` in the first line unquoted, the contents of the here-doc will be subject to parameter expansion, so your `$bar` expands to whatever you put in there.

If you can have linebreaks in your JSON, you can make it a little more readable:

```
foo=$(cat <<EOF
{
  "Comment": "Update DNSName.",
  "Changes": [
    {
      "Action": "UPSERT",
      "ResourceRecordSet": {
        "Name": "alex.",
        "Type": "A",
        "AliasTarget": {
          "HostedZoneId": "######",
          "DNSName": "$bar",
          "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
)
```

or even (first indent on each line must be a tab)

```
foo=$(cat <<-EOF
    {
      "Comment": "Update DNSName.",
      "Changes": [
        {
          "Action": "UPSERT",
          "ResourceRecordSet": {
            "Name": "alex.",
            "Type": "A",
            "AliasTarget": {
              "HostedZoneId": "######",
              "DNSName": "$bar",
              "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
    EOF
)
```

and to show how that is stored, including quoting (assuming that `bar=baz`):

```
$ declare -p foo
declare -- foo="{
  \"Comment\": \"Update DNSName.\",
  \"Changes\": [
    {
      \"Action\": \"UPSERT\",
      \"ResourceRecordSet\": {
        \"Name\": \"alex.\",
        \"Type\": \"A\",
        \"AliasTarget\": {
          \"HostedZoneId\": \"######\",
          \"DNSName\": \"baz\",
          \"EvaluateTargetHealth\": false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}"
```

Because this expands some shell metacharacters, you could run into trouble if your JSON contains something like `` ` ``, so alternatively, you could assign directly, but be careful about quoting around `$bar`:

```
foo='{"Comment":"Update DNSName.","Changes":[{"Action":"UPSERT","ResourceRecordSet":{"Name":"alex.","Type":"A","AliasTarget":{"HostedZoneId":"######","DNSName":"'"$bar"'","EvaluateTargetHealth":false}}}]}'
```

Notice the quoting for `$bar`: it's

```
"'"$bar"'"
│││    │││
│││    ││└ literal double quote
│││    │└ opening syntactical single quote
│││    └ closing syntactical double quote
││└ opening syntactical double quote
│└ closing syntactical single quote
└ literal double quote
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, and especially thanks for the quoting breakdown for bar, that solved a future problem!

Comment: Not only is that the solution I wanted, but it is the exact use-case. Thanks

Comment: closing syntactical single quote and opening syntactical single quote the other way round?

Comment: @Timo No, they're labeled correctly: the inner `"$bar"` is outside of the single-quoted string, so the first `'` closes a single quoted string, and the second `'` opens a new one.

Answer (score 18):

It can be *stored* safely; *generating* it is a different matter, since the contents of `$bar` may need to be encoded. Let a tool like `jq` handle creating the JSON.

```
var=$(jq -n --arg b "$bar" '{
  Comment: "Update DNSName.",
  Changes: [
    {
      Action: "UPSERT",
      ResourceRecordSet: {
        Name: "alex.",
        Type: "A",
        AliasTarget: {
          HostedZoneId: "######",
          DNSName: $b,
          EvaluateTargetHealth: false
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}')
```

Comment: jq is absolutely an option as we use it elsewhere, but I'm wondering about the lack of quotes - does jq handle putting quotes around everything or is that just something you left out in your example? AWS seems to demand quoted keypairs.

Comment: @Alex `jq` allows a key in a filter to be unquoted if it is a simply alphanumeric key; the generated JSON will have quotes.

Comment: This is **the** solution, because the `jq` checks the JSON so is possible catch eventual errors, and be sure that the generated JSON is always correct. (Aka: using right tool for the problem) :)

Comment: `n` from `man jq`: Don´t read any input at all! Instead, the filter is run  once  using null as the input. This is useful when using jq as a simple calculator or to construct JSON data from scratch. --- Sounds to me like not appending further data, just one time json creation.

Comment: I have `var=$(jq -n '{name:"a", mail:"b@", message:"hi f"}')` and `curl --data $var localhost` and get `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: "name"[...]`. Any help?

Comment: You didn't quote `$var`, so it is subject to word splitting. Only the part of `$var` preceding its first space is used as the argument to `-d`; the next bit is treated as the host name, not `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I face to the same issue, and find this quick solution. (working in `#!/bin/bash`, `#!/bin/zsh`)

```
SAMPLE='
{
    "Comment": "Update DNSName.",
    "Changes": [
        {
            "Action": "UPSERT",
            "ResourceRecordSet": {
                "Name": "alex.",
                "Type": "A",
                "AliasTarget": {
                    "HostedZoneId": "######",
                    "DNSName": "$bar",
                    "EvaluateTargetHealth": false
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
'
echo "${SAMPLE}" | tee output-file-path.json > /dev/null
```

And the result is exactly the same as the json file.