# groovy script - sh with variable

Tags: shell, jenkins, groovy

Missing something obvious. **How do I pass a variable from a groovy script into a shell command?** This is in the context of a Jenkinsfile if it matters for syntax.

```
def COLOR

node('nodename'){

    stage ('color') {

        COLOR = "green"
        echo "color is $COLOR"

        sh '''COLOR=${COLOR}
        echo $COLOR'''

    }
}
```

I expect to see the shell bit print `green`, but I'm getting the following;

```
[Pipeline] echo
color is green
[Pipeline] sh
[job] Running shell script
+ COLOR=
+ echo
```

I have to use triple quoting on the `sh` because of the content that's going to go in there once I get this straightened out.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to use double quotes instead of single in order to replace expressions in the string:

```
def COLOR

node('nodename'){

    stage ('color') {

        COLOR = "green"
        echo "color is $COLOR"

        sh """COLOR=${COLOR}
        echo $COLOR"""

    }
}
```

If single quotes need to be used for some reason, try concatenating using `+`:

```
sh '''COLOR=''' + COLOR + '''
    echo ''' + COLOR
```

Comment: argh, it seems you're right but that throws off what I was going to put in (quoting issues - trying to fit jq/json inside a variable). I assume there's no other workaround using the single quotes?

Comment: With multiline strings (using triple quoting) I doubt you can workaround much. But I don't exactly understand what you mean by "trying to fit jq/json inside a variable". The following works in Groovy: `def s = """root {
        key : "val"
        }"""`

Comment: it's a followup to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373176/store-json-directly-in-bash-script-with-variables trying to incorperate that solution into the groovy/shell combination. Probably outside the scope of this question to solve

Comment: @Alex A string concatenation can be used with single quotes (see updated answer).

Answer (score 4):

If the code here is meant to assign the groovy variable value ("green") to the environment variable COLOR, and `echo $COLOR` is meant to print out the shell variable, the `$` needs to be escaped like so that the shell can read it, like this:

```
sh """COLOR=${COLOR}
echo \$COLOR"""
```

Answer (score 0):

COLOR = "green"

sh label: '', script: "echo $COLOR"

Comment: A bit of explanation usually improves "code only" answers