# json string in bash variable

Tags: json, bash, shell

I am trying to use a bash variable to store json.

```
  testConfig=",{
    \"Classification\": \"mapred-site\",
    \"Properties\": {
        \"mapreduce.map.java.opts\": \"-Xmx2270m\",
        \"mapreduce.map.memory.mb\": \"9712\"
      }
    }"
```

echo $testConfig
Output: ,{

If I give it in a single line it works.
But i would like to store values in my variable in a clean format.

I tried using cat >>ECHO
That didn't work either

Any help is appreciated as to how I can store this in order to get the output in an expected format.
Thanks.

Comment: I think you can find the answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373176/store-json-directly-in-bash-script-with-variables

Comment: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells)

Comment: Cannot reproduce; the assignment is fine, and although you should quote the parameter expansion, that just preserves the newlines instead of replacing them with spaces.

Comment: In general, you should avoid trying to produce JSON by hand; let `jq` generate it for you. `testConfig=$(jq -n '{Classification: "mapred-site", Properties: { "mapreduce.map.java.opts": "-Xmx2270m", "mapreduce.map.memory.mb": "9712"}}')`. For hard-coded snippets like this, it doesn't matter, but it's very important if you start trying to generate dynamic JSON using parameters with unknown values (e.g., `{foo: "$bar"}`).

Comment: The fact that `testConfig` begins with a comma tells me you are building a larger JSON value using `testCongfig`, which makes the use of `jq` more important.

Answer (score 2):

You may use a here doc as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1655389/171318):

```
read -r -d '' testConfig <<'EOF'
{
    "Classification": "mapred-site",
    "Properties": {
        "mapreduce.map.java.opts": "-Xmx2270m",
        "mapreduce.map.memory.mb": "9712"
      }
}
EOF

# Just to demonstrate that it works ...
echo "$testConfig" | jq .
```

Doing so you can avoid quoting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [read -d](http://charles.lescampeurs.org/2012/08/10/bash-assign-a-multi-line-string-to-a-variable)

```
read -d '' testConfig <<EOF
,{ /
        "Classification": "mapred-site", 
        "Properties": {/
            "mapreduce.map.java.opts": "-Xmx2270m", 
            "mapreduce.map.memory.mb": "9712"
          }
        }
EOF

echo $testConfig;
```