# 'curl: option -----END: is unknown' using curl to upload public key to a jenkins SSH credential

Tags: json, curl, jenkins

I am trying to use this curl command to upload a private key to a Jenkins SSH credential:

```
JENKINS_PRIVATE_KEY_AS_STRING='-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEo...2qwu8diE -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'

curl -H $CRUMB -X POST "http://$USER:$API_TOKEN@$JENKINS_HOST/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials" \
--data-urlencode "json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "jenkins-ssh",
    "username": "jenkins",
    "password": "",
    "privateKeySource": {
      "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource",
      "privateKey": "$JENKINS_PRIVATE_KEY_AS_STRING",
    },
    "description": "jenkins-ssh-credentials",
    "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
  }
}"
```

But when I run the above it fails with:

```
curl: option -----END: is unknown
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Why is the string in the variable `$JENKINS_PRIVATE_KEY_AS_STRING` causing an error and how do I fix it?

Based on below answer I have also tried:

```
curl -H $CRUMB -X POST "http://$USER:$API_TOKEN@$JENKINS_HOST/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials" \
--data-urlencode "json={
  \"\": \"0\",
  \"credentials\": {
    \"scope\": \"GLOBAL\",
    \"id\": \"jenkins-ssh\",
    \"username\": \"jenkins\",
    \"password\": \"\",
    \"privateKeySource\": {
      \"stapler-class\": \"com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource\",
      \"privateKey\": \"$JENKINS_PRIVATE_KEY_AS_STRING\",
    },
    \"description\": \"jenkins-ssh-credentials\",
    \"stapler-class\": \"com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey\"
  }
}"
```

But that give the error:

```
: Specified type class com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey is not assignable to the expected class com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$PrivateKeySource
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:671)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to instantiate class com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$PrivateKeySource from {"stapler-class":"com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey","privateKey":"-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- MIIEo...2qwu8diE -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"}
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl$TypePair.convertJSON(RequestImpl.java:680)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.bindJSON(RequestImpl.java:478)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.RequestImpl.instantiate(RequestImpl.java:777)
Caused: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to convert the privateKeySource parameter of the constructor public com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey(com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsScope,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$PrivateKeySource,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
```

But not sure that its related to the curl part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution based on the post:

[Store JSON directly in bash script with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373176/store-json-directly-in-bash-script-with-variables/43373520)

So the trick was to quote the variable like this: `"'"$JENKINS_PRIVATE_KEY_AS_STRING"'"`. The full working example becomes:

```
curl -H $CRUMB -X POST "http://$USER:$API_TOKEN@$JENKINS_HOST/credentials/store/system/domain/_/createCredentials" \
--data-urlencode 'json={
  "": "0",
  "credentials": {
    "scope": "GLOBAL",
    "id": "jenkins-ssh",
    "username": "jenkins",
    "password": "",
    "privateKeySource": {
      "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource",
      "privateKey": "'"$JENKINS_PRIVATE_KEY_AS_STRING"'",
    },
    "description": "jenkins-ssh-credentials",
    "stapler-class": "com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.sshcredentials.impl.BasicSSHUserPrivateKey"
  }
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix argument quoting:

```
                 v
--data-urlencode "json={
  "": "0",
  ^
```

Instead, escape `"` characters that appear in the argument string:

```
--data-urlencode "json={
  \"\": \"0\",
[...]
```

Comment: But left hand side is meant to be the empty string or can you be more specific?

Comment: When using `"` for quoting the argument of `--data-urlencode`, you must escape such quotes inside the argument. I'll amend the answer accordingly.

Comment: That just result in another error. See updated post.

Comment: This is because in `"` quotes, you also need to esape the `$` sign in `$DirectEntryPrivateKeySource`. When you escape properly, there is no need to "split" the argument string as you did in your own answer.