# Github api not parsing multi line shell variables

Tags: json, shell, github-api

I've got a text param (from jenkins job dsl plugin) in jenkins configuration which allows you to enter a multi line comment. I'm using that variable for the body value when posting a release to a github repository from a shell script. I'm getting this error that says problem parsing json and I can't find a workaround. I'll try to give you an example below. Please help.

```
PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN="random"
TAG_NAME="12.0.0"
VERSION_BUMP="major"
MIGRATION_DOCUMENT="This is first line
This is second line"

curl -i \
-H "Authorization: token ${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
-d '{"tag_name": "'"${TAG_NAME}"'", "name": "'"${VERSION_BUMP}"'", \
"body": "'"${MIGRATION_DOCUMENT}"'"}' \
https://github.deere.com/api/v3/repos/randomOrg/testRepo/releases
```

Comment: So the goal is to use github markdown as part of that multi line text param input and post a release to github with the aforementioned curl command. so the variable MIGRATION_DOCUMENT would be a custom multiline comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This

```
{ "a": "b
c" }
```

is invalid JSON because a string must not contain control characters such as newlines.

If you have a string containing newlines, you can convert them to `\n` using shell parameter expansion:

```
$ var='a
b'
$ echo "$var"
a
b
$ echo "${var//$'\n'/'\n'}"
a\nb
```

So, to feed your string into your JSON object, use

```
"body": "'"${MIGRATION_DOCUMENT//$'\n'/'\n'}"'"
```

at the end of your JSON object.

Also, if you use line continuation in single quotes such as

```
var='abc \
def'
```

then the backslash and the linebreak are literal:

```
$ echo "$var"
abc \
def
```

Don't use line continuation like that in single quoted strings.

All in all:

```
curl -i \
    -H "Authorization: token ${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
    -d '{"tag_name": "'"${TAG_NAME}"'", "name": "'"${VERSION_BUMP}"'", "body": "'"${MIGRATION_DOCUMENT//$'\n'/'\n'}"'"}' \
    https://github.deere.com/api/v3/repos/randomOrg/testRepo/releases
```

If you really want to, you can still use line continuation, but it has to be in a double quoted context:

```
curl -i \
    -H "Authorization: token ${PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN}" \
    -d '{"tag_name": "'"${TAG_NAME}"'", "name": "'"${VERSION_BUMP}"'", '"\
        "'"body": "'"${MIGRATION_DOCUMENT//$'\n'/'\n'}"'"}' \
    https://github.deere.com/api/v3/repos/randomOrg/testRepo/releases
```

As a side note, you shouldn't use all uppercase names for variables; those are reserved for environment variables, see [the POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html) (fourth paragraph).

Comment: Thanks. That worked for the new line. Do you mind pointing me to docs on what you did there. I'd like to extend that so I can use github markdown as part of that multiline comment.

Comment: It would be wise to use `jq` instead of hoping that the text is valid once the linefeeds are replaced

Comment: @thatotherguy Agreed – then we're firmly in territory excellently handled by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43373675/3266847).

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks for introducing me to `jq`. I believe it'll be of great help for me here.