# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 0

Tags: node.js, json, bash, express, curl

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
const fs = require("fs");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());



// http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
app.use(express.static("public"));

const dbFile = "./.data/sqlite.db";
const exists = fs.existsSync(dbFile);
const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile);

db.serialize(() => {
  if (!exists) {
    db.run(
      "CREATE TABLE UserData (UserID INTEGER, Points INTEGER, Warnings INTEGER, Suspendions INTEGER, Blacklisted TEXT)"
    );
    console.log("New table UserData created!");

  }
});

app.post("/adduserdatacard", (request, response) => {
  console.log(`add to userdata ${request.body.userid}`);


  const userid = request.body.userid;
  const points = request.body.points;
  db.run(`INSERT INTO UserData (UserID,Points,Warnings,Suspendions,Blacklisted) VALUES (?,?,0,0,'false')`,userid, points, error => {
    if (error) {
      response.send({ message: "error" });
    } else {
      response.send({ message: "success" });
    }
  });
});
```

I'm confused due to the fact that no ' is in my code. I am running the API via CURL with

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"UserID":1,"Points":1234}' http://lts-database.glitch.me
```

Why would it be telling me such an error if there is no quote? I've already tied replacing the quote around the JSON and it says invalid token U then.

Comment: What does the console.log show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do in fact have a `'` single-quote character in the string you pass to your post endpoint.

This is the string you pass

```
'{"UserID":1,"Points":1234}'
```

It should be

```
"{\"UserID\":1,\"Points\":1234}"
```

Putting JSON strings in shell commands like `curl` is a notorious pain in the neck, as you are discovering. You must wrap them in double quotes and then escape the double quotes inside them.

You may find this question helpful. [Store JSON directly in bash script with variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43373176/store-json-directly-in-bash-script-with-variables)